# Complete Removal of Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-neon

I use Eclipse Neon under Windows 10.

I installed a plugin (MonjaDB) using Eclipse Market Place. As I didn't find the plugin to be very useful I uninstalled it using Help->About->Installation Details->Installed Software->Uninstall. Sadly, however, this didn't seem to fully remove the plugin.

I now have a small red square on the right hand side of my workspace in the shortcut toolbar. This cannot be removed using the close option. I went so far as to remove my installation of Eclipse and the .eclipse directory in my home area but after a reinstall the square is still there.

Presumably this means that it is somehow associated with the project in my workspace?? Does anyone have any ideas how to remove this annoying square?

**EDIT:**

I have noticed two things

1. The MonjaDB perspective is hanging around somehow and
2. If I press the little red square on the right it opens an empty tab in the tab set to the right (where mylyn sits) with the title of DB Tree but I cannot remove it.

I have added three screen shots

[MonjaDb perspective Partly Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKFED.jpg)

[image: Empty tabs open]

[image: The little red square]

Comment: can you add a screenshot? i assume that the square is part of a 'view' from the uninstalled plugin

Comment: I think you are correct

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your current perspective is the one that was uninstalled. Just try opening a new one via the `Open Perspective` toolbar button that's close to thevred square, and then you can try right-click > Close on the red square.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. I have switched perspectives, closed all perspectives and reset perspective independently and none of them get rid of the red square. If I press the red square it creates an empty tab labelled DB Tree.that sits in the tab set to the right of the normal perspectives (where Mylyn etc. usually sit)

Answer (score 0):

At least a part of this is intentional...when the implementation class of a view no longer exists we leave the view 'open' but are *supposed* to show an "Error Part'. The reason to leave it up is to handle cases where a user has installed a new eclipse and opens his old workspace *before* installing the extensions. If we were to remove the views the user would have to set up their perspectives again once they had installed the extension.

Note that resetting the perspective won't work because the class implementing IPespectiveFactory no longer exists.

Closing the perspective and opening a new, different, one should work. If the perspective you open has visible views that are no longer available you should just close them.